# Which ChromeDriver & Headless Chrome versions exist that are compatible with ruby 2.7?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda, google-chrome-headless, ruby-2.7

**The issue**

I have a web scraper running in AWS lambda but **in a few weeks AWS lambda will stop supporting Ruby 2.7**. I built my scraper last year using [this tutorial](https://dev.to/mknycha/serverless-web-scraper-in-ruby-tutorial-50hg).

I need to find a version of chrome driver & headless chrome that is compatible with **Ruby 2.7**, But I don't know exactly where to start.

I have looked at the [ChromeDriver's downloads portal](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) But I don't see any indication there that Chrome driver will work for ruby 2.7 or any other specific version of ruby for that matter.

The code I have works by accessing the ChromeDriver binary and starting it inside a specific folder

I downloaded the specific binaries I am using by running these commands:

```sh
# serverless chrome
wget https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/releases/download/v1.0.0-37/stable-headless-chromium-amazonlinux-2017-03.zip
unzip stable-headless-chromium-amazonlinux-2017-03.zip -d bin/
rm stable-headless-chromium-amazonlinux-2017-03.zip

# chromedriver
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip -d bin/
rm chromedriver_linux64.zip
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem? i have a problem same as you. So when i just migrate ruby version 2.5 to 2.7, there were problem like "Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
   unable to connect to chromedriver http://127.0.0.1:9515". My Serverless chrome and chromedriver version are same as you.

Comment: @Hoonki I have found a way to make it work, what you need to do is change your Lambda from using a .zip file to use a docker image stored in ECR, I'll write a propper response for my question after I am done doing just that.

Comment: Thanks. But what does using docker image mean? Should we still need using ruby 2.5 environment?

Comment: @Hoonki You can create your own custom docker image to use in Lambda from scratch. You only need to follow a guide like this one https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html I have been working on this question for a while now. I'll respond my own question and create a tutorial in https://dev.to/ but I think you should be able to figure this one out on your own. Or you can wait until I give an update.

Comment: @AlvaroAlday I set it up in a docker using the ecr lambda ruby2.7 image but still get the same error. Curious to see what your Dockerfile looks like.

Comment: Hey guys. i've tried headless-chrome version https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/releases/tag/v1.0.0-57 for amazon linux 2. The ruby 2.7 aws lambda environment's os version is amazon linux 2.
But it doesn't work... i got an error that "unable to connect chromedriver 127.0.0.1 ~~". Did you find the solution?

Comment: I updated the post and included the Docker file that I used. @HarrisJT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

I found the solution to this problem. Ruby 2.7 that Lambda offers by default runs on top of Amazon Linux 2 (which lacks many important libraries & dependencies), unfortunately, there's nothing you can do to change that.

However, [Amazon offers you the ability to run your code in a custom docker image that can be up to 10GB in size.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html)

I fixed this problem by creating my own image using the following Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/ruby:2.7

# Install dependencies needed to run MySQL & Chrome

RUN yum -y install libX11
RUN yum -y install dejavu-sans-fonts
RUN yum -y install procps
RUN yum -y install mysql-devel
RUN yum -y install tree
RUN mkdir /var/task/lib
RUN cp /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18 /var/task/lib
RUN gem install bundler
RUN yum -y install wget
RUN yum -y groupinstall 'Development Tools'

# Ruby Gems

ADD Gemfile ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/
ADD Gemfile.lock ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/
RUN bundle config set path 'vendor/bundle' && \
    bundle install

# Install chromedriver & chromium

RUN mkdir ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/bin

# Chromium
RUN wget https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/releases/download/v1.0.0-37/stable-headless-chromium-amazonlinux-2017-03.zip
RUN unzip stable-headless-chromium-amazonlinux-2017-03.zip -d ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/bin/
RUN rm stable-headless-chromium-amazonlinux-2017-03.zip

# Chromedriver

RUN wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip -d ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/bin/
RUN rm chromedriver_linux64.zip

# Copy function code

COPY app.rb ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

RUN tree
RUN ls ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/bin
# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "app.handle" ]
```

**Notes**

1. If your code was previously deployed using a zip file you will have to either destroy the previous function or create a second function with the code update, it all comes down to how you want to handle deployment.
2. It is possible to automate the deployment process using the [**serverless framework**](https://www.serverless.com/blog/container-support-for-lambda)